# SpringBoot filtering: At least one property must be given

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to implement filtering and pagination to my spring boot application and I've ran into an issue.

This is my controller: page and size have a default value and every other parameter should be optional like below.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('service_manager')")
@RequestMapping(path = "/clients", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Page<ClientResponse> getClients(
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int size,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String companyName,
            @RequestParam(required = false) BigInteger firmRegNo,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String address,
            @RequestParam(required = false) BigInteger contractNo,
            @RequestParam(required = false) BigInteger monthlyPay,
            @RequestParam(required = false) User.UserStatus status
            ) {
    ClientListRequest request = new ClientListRequest(companyName, firmRegNo, address, contractNo, monthlyPay, status);
    return clientService.getAllClients(request, of(page, size, Sort.Direction.DESC))
            .map(ClientResponse::new);
}
```

When making a GET request to "http://localhost:8080/clients?companyName=Selver" I'm getting this response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-02-18T07:40:44.182+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "At least one property must be given!",
    "path": "/clients"
}
```

The same response comes without the parameters too. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `Integer` class instead of `int` for `@RequestParam` declarations?

Comment: Tried, same result :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the mistake:

```
return clientService.getAllClients(request, of(page, size, Sort.Direction.DESC))
                .map(ClientResponse::new);
```

needs at least one property after `Sort.Direction.DESC`, which to sort by by default. I used "createTime" of a client to do so and got it to work!

```
return clientService.getAllClients(request, of(page, size, Sort.Direction.DESC, "createTime"))
                .map(ClientResponse::new);
```